# Keep type hints for a TypeScript function that can take any arguments

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to define the type for a property which is a function. This function can accept any arguments (and any number of args), but must return a string.

I'm aware that I can type such a function like this:

```
(...args: never[]) => string
```

However this results in no type safety or type hints.

**Example** ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAKAdJghgJwOYDOAXFAHYQBuEOA2gLoCUyAfFAcDgJal4BQvAYzil2ULABswACywl4iFKiZJWAA1KJceAK4BbCKWAFV-CdKzoARriVQA9HagA5RKEhQp3IwBooAd08BKShOAigIAA9IAWAIABMQ0ihgTzCBLAIIfiERYChLHCwKODkEZDRZNg5uPGU1bUyw4WgtPQNgABIAbywAXxNeAqK4Kxs7ACo2KThtcQThcRAxcXE4PygARiquHjF8NsMocbsmBygASVyILAS8TiowlOg3aE9DElVrHAxsfGIySjUegMEjsHZ4AY5URBXDiTgQUoKCokUh6SzUXyWUHVHh1KCqBoQR5+TT7fSGf7dPpiUgJbqWfrZGQ4OEQUbfCZTGZzcJRCAxKAAJj2OnJPjEZDR1BpCSw2xqRxO9kcl3Y11u9yJySkz3Ary8Hy+P3QWn+5CotEY2PBJiAA))

```
type Foo = (...args: never[]) => string

const alpha: Foo = () => `no arguments`

alpha() // No type hints, which is expected in this case

const bravo: Foo = (a: string) => `uses one argument${a}`

bravo(/* should only allow 1 string argument */) // Instead gives the type hint: `bar(...args: never[]): string`

const charlie: Foo = (a: number, b: string) => `uses two arguments: ${a} and ${b}`

charlie(/* should expect 2 arguments, a number and a string */) // Instead gives the type hint: `bar(...args: never[]): string`
```

That is, when typing the open parenthesis after the function name, it should hint at which arguments this particular function accepts.

Comment: You might want to make your playground link have the same contents as the plaintext.  Right now it refers to `bar` methods (kind of, you also have `alpha.bravo()` in there ).

Comment: @jcalz Indeed, I updated the answer while you were answering (thank you!) so I have now reverted it such that it matches the format of your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Foo` type accepts any `string`-returning function.  But when you assign a value to a variable of type `Foo`, the compiler does not track the particular value you've assigned.  In some sense the compiler treats `alpha`, `bravo`, and `charlie`, as opaque boxes labeled `Foo`, and that's all it knows about the contents.  So while it's really easy to *provide* a value of type `Foo`, it's almost impossible to *consume* one.

This forgetfulness is the general behavior for variables of non-[union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) types.  For *union* types, there is [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) where the *appearent* type of a variable will be narrowed based on the inferred type of the assigned value.  That lets you write `const x: string | undefined = "hello"; x.toUpperCase();` without error, since `x` is narrowed from `string | undefined` to `string` by the assignment.  It would be nice if this worked in some way for non-unions, and there is a longstanding request at [microsoft/TypeScript#16976](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16976) to do this, but I don't see any indication this will ever be implemented (it would be a big breaking change to do so). You can't plausibly represent `Foo` as a union type, and unions of functions [have other complicating behavior](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) anyway, so this is not a feasible solution for you.

Instead, my suggestion is that you really want something like the so-called `satisfies` operator, as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#47920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920) and originally [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481).  You want `alpha` and `bravo` and `charlie` to *satisfy* the `Foo` type without being *widened* to the `Foo` type.  There's no built-in operator that works this way, but you can implement a generic identity helper function that gives you this behavior (this workaround is discussed in those GitHub issues):

```
type Foo = (...args: never) => string
const asFoo = <F extends Foo>(f: F) => f;
```

Instead of annotating variables like `const x: Foo = ...`, you use the helper function like `const x = asFoo(...)`.  Here's how it works:

```
const alpha = asFoo(() => `no arguments`);
console.log(alpha()) // okay

const bravo = asFoo((a: string) => `uses one argument${a}`);
bravo() // error, argument of type sting expected

const charlie = asFoo((a: number, b: string) => `uses two arguments: ${a} and ${b}`);
charlie() // error, two arguments expected
```

Looks good!

Note that if you actually want to *use* `Foo` objects programmatically you will need to keep track of the arguments list types by using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), like this:

```
type GenericFoo<A extends any[]> = (...args: A) => string;
function useFoo<A extends any[]>(foo: GenericFoo<A>, ...args: A): string {
  return foo(...args);
}
useFoo(alpha); // okay
useFoo(bravo, "a"); // okay
useFoo(bravo, 123); // error, number is not string
useFoo(bravo); // error, expect another argument
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAKUWANgLxQb2BRXGniVQAkos4oAnAo4lAFwE86UAxAe15QBeFAAoAdBLD0A5jABcJKADcGASiEA+FDFb0AliGnBmxRLxA6UYGHwHCAPNxRQAHqyggAJjB78NIgDMFbnVBLQCAbmMWFDMLVitaAAswISsbfhERUK0AAxABKWkAV2gQVhhc1SiTWPMYXiwoMSxeaRFsOBTs1WiWOMsAI3owJTt02yywBR19QxyUXOKYWBRzVCLSj1YAEnwwAF8qmpjh0d4RAHoAKm0k3mKsTzWQLHZE1oB3FABGbV0DNIrDItuUUNdLupLpdnC46IgKr9-nMgUU+qZ6glECl6Fg9KhhNZJh0FCBSoMGAAaFCDGYA+aaRbLVasT6FEFlCoKPaHKxeFB7QZHaro2I4vFQK63GD3R7PVzwhIAJmBJU5MGpqTJEApjDA-NSs0B4MhKGhsMVPhVRRgoo4XAA4h4GHpELZ7ABBWHuLw+fXsADaAF0tMJxJIZPIUB6FkbDFEYgFiiAEXpzChme6va4fd4+YGQ4F+AonSAXW7+J6NNSJGIbQoY3SUUwYsR6FBWMV6CAUAFMrWbSKYgdapnMp0UtUzTDeABrMDsUcrSZnMbUgBEYHXU-Nc4XS6gK5Ga9+SoAzDuYQx6Lx6NTtbqUHofAUEnGjDExxdV7xL856Ded4WlACJ8rwrBJAwqqgqwzAjsABxAA)